# OVerloaded function calling issue

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

I have 2 overloaded function say - func1 and func2 -

Func1 is -

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> bool AreIdentical(const std::pair<T1, T2> 
&lhs, const std::pair<T1, T2> &rhs)
{
  //some code
}
```

Func2 is -

```
 template<typename T> bool AreIdentical(typename std::map<int, 
 std::vector<T>>::iterator itOrig,
 typename std::map<int, std::vector<T>>::iterator itNew)
 {
    //some code
 }
```

I am trying to call the function **AreIdentical** in below manner -

```
int main()
{
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> orgitem;
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> newitem;
newitem[0];
orgitem[0];
AreIdentical(*orgitem.begin(), *newitem.begin());

return 0;
}
```

Now, interesting thing is,  my **origitem** and **newitem** is of **map** type but always **Func1** is getting called which takes parameter **pair** type instead of **Func2**.

Do anyone have any clue why is it happening so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orgitem.begin()` is an iterator.  But `*orgitem.begin()` is the object the iterator points at, which is a `std::pair<const int, std::vector<int>>`.

If you had

```
AreIdentical(orgitem.begin(), newitem.begin());
```

without the dereferencing `*` operators, that would not be able to call the `pair` overload.

But in fact it won't work either, because in your second overload the parameter `T` is not in a deducible context.  The only way to call it is:

```
AreIdentical<int>(orgitem.begin(), newitem.begin());
```

You might be able to "fix" this by changing the iterator overload to just accept any iterator whose value type has members `first` and `second`:

```
template <typename Iter>
auto AreIdentical(Iter itOrig, Iter itNew)
    -> decltype((*itOrig).first, (*itOrig).second, bool{});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @aschelper! you are right! it worked!

Comment: I just accidentally used AreIdentical(orgitem.begin(), newitem.begin());
instead of AreIdentical(*orgitem.begin(), *newitem.begin()); I am still facing the same issue after implementing ur suggested changes.

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar It works okay for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa27336e28021651

Comment: you called AreIdentical as  - AreIdentical(orgitem.begin(), newitem.begin());

I want to call as  - AreIdentical(*orgitem.begin(), *newitem.begin());

Is there any possibility to modify the overloaded method which satisfies the call as I mentioned above?

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar Well, `*orgitem.begin()` is a `pair`, so that will call your `pair` overload. There's no good way to get back from a container element to its iterator.